Guy brings his friend's sister to a wedding
Movie is about a guy who needs to go to a wedding in his home town, not clear whose (might be his sister's) and he has to bring someone along because his father is terminally ill and guilt tripped him. So he takes the former kid sister of one of his buddies who had a massive crush on him back in the day. The parents give them an apartment to stay in and they end up falling in love, blah blah blah.
It starts out with the girl in an airport bar taking some pills from an air hostess and mixing them with alcohol and losing it (it's a comedy, trust me). It's a recent movie, made in perhaps the last 5-8 years (it's recent to me) and it's sort of an independent/direct to DVD type movie. Has some raunchy moments so not one of those Hallmark channel ones. That’s all I have.

Sounds like you're after romantic comedy One Small Hitch from 2012:

Molly Mahoney (Aubrey Dollar) is flying home to Chicago for her mom's wedding... bringing a "Mystery Man" with her, but when she discovers this Mystery Man has a Mystery Wife, she dumps him at the curbside check-in. She ends up crying on the shoulder of childhood friend Josh Shiffman (Shane McRae), who is flying home for the same wedding. Emotionally drained, Molly passes out in Josh's arms just as he gets a phone call from his parents. Josh learns that his father is dying and his only regret is that he will not get to meet the woman who will one day become his son's wife. Desperate to fulfill his dad's final wish, Josh claims he has already met that woman... close family friend: Molly Mahoney. 

They meet in the airport lounge, when Molly is zonked out on sleeping pills she got on the plane. Here's the trailer:



